# How to get the CSS width of a mobile device in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP.NET MVC, how do I get the width of the screen in terms of css pixels?  I'm on a Nexus 5, and if I do `Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth`, it gives me the width in terms of the pixel density (that is 1080), but what I am trying to get is the CSS width, should be more like 480px.

Comment: you should just have a responsive CSS design

Comment: That's why I need it...

Comment: Well I don't know many fluid layouts that require to read the screen size! Some might use media queries to target a stylesheet

Comment: Yeah for the most part I am using media queries.  But I have a progress-bar-kinda element that needs to size relative to the screen's width, and the calculation logic of the width is in the Razor, and depends on a bunch of other things, not just the screen width, so I can't simply use CSS/media queries to adjust the width.

Comment: I would say getting the screen res within the razor view is a hack not using CSS to control elements

Comment: In CSS media queries, is it possible to set the width using a formula? For my progressbar, width = Model.x / Model.y * DeviceWidth.  Model.x and Model.y are values from the DB.

Comment: As a percentage you can. Have everything setup in css but the width of the progress bar, then apply in the razor view (Model.x / Model.y * 100)% The bar is now Z% in width

Comment: The problem is that in my case the widths are not always proportional that way in terms of percentages.  For example, if the screen width is 1920, the progress bar width is actually lower than when the screen width is 1200 (as I have multiple columns for the 1920), whereas if the screen width is  1366 or less, I have only one column and then the percentage-based width kicks in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to simply use [JQuery's Window Width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) - `$(window).width()` - populate that in to the hiddenfield and you can get it on the server side in FormCollection.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I ended up having to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're right! The code you're using will always provide you with the Screen's pixels. That are counted to be 1080.

To get the CSS values, you can use JavaScript instead!

You cannot read the values on run time. Because ASP.NET don't deal in that!

I can give you a simple suggestion:

Try this:

```
var wid = screen.width;
```

Now you can write it in the document!